# "Any kind of CAR" vs "Any kind of CARS"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, singular-vs-plural

What sentence between those two is valid, using singular or plural with "any kind of" ?

> Any kind of car

Or

> Any kind of cars

Comment: Individuals may have different preferences, but there's no universally-observed grammatical principle requiring or preventing any of the four permutations in, for example, *He avoids any **kind / kinds** of **fruit / fruits**.* Note that if you replace ***any*** by ***all*** you can't use singular ***kind***, but it's still a stylistic choice whether to pluralise ***fruit*** in that example context.

Comment: Need some more context I think.

Answer (score 1):

The use of kind and car need to match.

Singular:

> Any kind of car

Plural

> All kinds of cars

Answer (score 0):

my search in "google ngram" about your question showed me that all is right with both of these sentences. But for me they have slightly different meaning from each other.

When you talk about car from range of them, you can use "Any kind of car" and anyway it will be talking inside category of usual cars (if you don't have any specific context with your sentence that can change meaning).

When you talk "Any kind of cars" it can be about different more common categories of different cars (and might suppose attention on these categories in your talking).

Schematically:

1) About any car from one category of cars (like usual cars not specific).

2) About any category from different categories of cars (like sport cars, family cars or so on).

Comment: Which ngram are you looking at? [This one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=any+kind+of+car%2Cany+kind+of+cars&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) would hint that the form with the singular is far more common, and the form with the plural is rarely used.

Comment: @J R, I looked ngram not only for [car-cars] case but for different singular-plural like man-men or so on and it came to my answer . And I agree with you, yes, plural is more rare but not so rare as mistake. I suppose so about it.